# KOA - Passport with Password Grant strategy

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, passport-facebook, koa-passport

Hi I am trying to implement password grant strategy with Koa-passport. I configured a strategy as below

```
passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy({
            tokenURL: "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/oauth/token",
            clientID: "democlient1",
            clientSecret: "democlientsecret1",
            scope: "profile",
            grant_type: "password",
            customHeaders: {Authorization: "Basic ZGVtb2NsaWVudDE6ZGVtb2NsaWVudHNlY3JldDE=", scope: "profile" }
        },
        async (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any,
            done: (error: any, user?: any, options?: IVerifyOptions) => void) => {
            console.log("Details ", accessToken, profile);
            done(null, profile);
        }));
```

And this is how i try to authenticate,

```
return passport.authenticate("password-grant", {
                username: "test",
                password: "test"
            }, (err: any, user: any, info: any, status: any) => {
                console.log("Inside Callback method");
            })(ctx, next);
```

Could anyone please help me. The above code does not call the token URL. But the control come inside to the callback method defined in passport.authenticate.

Thanks in advance.